# Simpifying expressions with binomial coefficients

Tags: simplifying-expressions, combinatorics

I wrote:

```
Simplify[Binomial[n, k] - Binomial[n - 1, k]]
```

I expected Mathematica to simplify this according to Pascal's identity to:

```
Binomial[n-1, k-1]
```

but it did not do this. Is there a way to tell it to use binomial coefficient identities in the simplification?

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, k] - Binomial[n - 1, k]] // FullSimplify
```

> $$ \frac{\Gamma (n)}{\Gamma (k) \Gamma (-k+n+1)} $$

Comment: I suppose you could follow this with a replacement rule: `/. Gamma[a_]/(Gamma[b_] Gamma[c_]) /; c == a - b + 1 :> Binomial[a - 1, b - 1]`

Comment: @Mr Wizard: Thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, why doesn't `/. {Gamma[a_] Gamma[b_] :> Gamma[a + b - 1]/Binomial[a + b - 2, a - 1]` work?